# Preparation for app release with coredata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

i am coming to an end with creating version 1.0 of my new project. for the first time i am using coredata.

the application only uses 1 model, all data will be supplied by the user (so i do not load any data with the application).

of course i already working on updates for the application on different branches and see some changes in the datamodel in the future. the changes on the model will only consist of:

- addition of entities
- addition of attributes to existing entities
- the entities do not have any relation with each other.

i have read through: [iPhone app with CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453438/iphone-app-with-coredata)
from there i went on to: [Lightweight Migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1), where i read about coredatas ability to update its model automatically if changes are minor (if i read correctly my changes are included there).

in the apple migration doc i found the code for automatic migration:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *storeURL = <#The URL of a persistent store#>;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = <#The coordinator#>;
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

BOOL success = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:<#Store type#>
                    configuration:<#Configuration or nil#> URL:storeURL
                    options:options error:&error];
if (!success) {
    // Handle the error.
}
```

my questions are the following:

- where would i put this code? i found now additional information on it
- do i assume that this code will only be necessary in the updated version of the app?
- do i need any other preparations on my version 1.0 app to allow later motifications & updates to coredata, or do i not have to think about this in the first release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I have this code in the method

   -(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator

There should already be code like

```
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
```

if you have let Xcode create the core data methods.

1. This code is only necessary in the update which introduces a new model.
2. As far as I know, no. This is all.

Comment: and if you add a new model, yon only give it another version ID, and leave the old one in the application and everything is done by itself?

Comment: and if i add an attribute to an existing entity - if updated with default value, will all 'old' objects in the context get updated with the new default value?

Comment: Add a new model by selecting your existing model and then selecting Editor>Add Model Version... . For the default value: I assume that this is the case, but I don't know.

Comment: The old objects only get updated to the new default value **if it is a required attribute** but are left at nil if it isn't required.  Simply handle the `nil` case in your code to supply a default value if needed (and it isn't a required attribute).  Also, be sure that you don't change your original data model, only the new version so that it can map the differences!